# Selenium won't load page after a certain time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python program in selenium that goes through several links stored in a file. The file can easily have more than 2000 links. But I noticed that after a certain time, Selenium doesn't load the pages unless I manually open the browser. This is bothersome since the browser is intended to be hidden anyway.

Someone knows where that comes from ? The program is very basic, it can be assimilated to that :

```
for link in links:
   driver.get(link)
   #Some actions here related to the source code of the page.
   time.sleep(3)
```

Thanks.

edit :

I thik my problem is related to focus issues, I found this page : https://makandracards.com/makandra/12661-how-to-solve-selenium-focus-issues
But I don't understand the solution that it proposes, since I have no knowledge in javascript.

Comment: Are you seeing any error on _Selenium doesn't load the pages_?

Comment: No nothing, it's just a blank page and selenium considers that nothing is wrong.

Comment: I am asking about the error logs/stack trace in the console